# Comparison Operator Precedence and Binding

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why the expression 1>=2==5<=4 results in False?

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of python 3, the operators >=,==,<= have same precedence and left to right binding. As per the rule, the evaluation of the statement should be in the following manner (assuming True=1 and False=0):

```
1>=2==5<=4
=> False==5<=4
=> False<=4
=> True
```

I am unable to understand why this expression evaluated as False. I am new to python. Can anyone please help me with the understanding of this operators precedence?

Comment: They didn't say "left to right binding". They said "left-to-right ***chaining*** feature as described in the [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) section"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, it's not exactly evaluated left to right. The `and`'s are implicit

It's false because at least one (the first) condition is false, causing a short circuit evaluation

```
1>=2 and 2==5 and 5<=4
=> False and (doesn't matter)
=> False
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g.,

> x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z.
>
> 1>=2==5<=4 can be written as
>
> **1>=2 and 2==5 and 5<=4**

You can learn more about the comparison operators in python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 0):

Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `1 >= 2 == 5 <= 4`is equivalent to `1 >= 2` and `2 == 5` and `5 <= 4` except that `2` and `5` is evaluated only once (but in `1>=2==5` case `5` is not evaluated at all when `1 >= 2` is found to be false and same in case when `2==5<=4`, `4` is not evaluated at all when `2 ==5` is fount to be false).
Note that `1 >= 2 == 5 <= 4` doesn’t imply any kind of comparison between `1` and `4`, and also `2` and `4`.

Mark answer if helpful.

Comment: Please read the question. In the question, I have mentioned that the expression **results in False not True** and I am trying to get an explanation for that. I have shared my understanding in the code section not the actual result.